# Google Speech API not working in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I am using Google Cloud Speech API in Node.js. When I send a local audio file it gives the result but when I try to send a live stream it gets stopped within a second. Can anyone help me with this?

I am using this file: [recognize.js](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/speech)

1. this is the code when I pass the audio file to google speech API. here it is working fine.I am passing the audio file stored in fileName sending into google speech API

   ```
     function sample() {
     const projectId = 'project id';
     let file = "conf.json" //google exported this for you 
     var speech = require('@google-cloud/speech')({
         projectId: 'project id',
         keyFilename: 'Speech to text-a5ff6058e586.json'
     });
     const fs = require('fs');
     const fileName = 'C:/Users/nap1225/Downloads/audio-files/audio_001.wav';
     //       const fileName = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/SpeechWatson/public/audio/Us_English_Broadband_Sample_2.wav';
     //       const fileName = 'Sample 1.wav';
     //       const fileName = 'C:/Users/nap1225/Desktop/dolo.wav';
     // Reads a local audio file and converts it to base64
     const fileMp3 = fs.readFileSync(fileName);
     const audioBytes = fileMp3.toString('base64');
     const audio = {
         content: audioBytes
     };
     const config = {
         encoding: 'LINEAR16',
         sampleRateHertz: 16000,
         languageCode: 'en-US',
         speechContexts: {
             "phrases": ["refsum"]
         }
     };
     const request = {
         audio: audio,
         config: config
     };
     speech.recognize(request)
         .then((results) => {
             const transcription = results[0].results[0].alternatives[0].transcript;
             console.log(`Transcription: `, transcription);
         })
         .catch((err) => {
             console.error('ERROR:', err);


       });
   }
   sample();
   ```

   2.here is the code I am sending stream audio.when I execute this code in, it is recording for 1 second and get stopped

   ```
   function streamingMicRecognize () {
     // [START speech_streaming_mic_recognize]
     // Imports the Google Cloud client library
     const record = require('node-record-lpcm16');
           const projectId = 'project id';
           let file="conf.json"//google exported this for you 
           const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech')({
               projectId: 'project id',
               keyFilename: 'Speech to text-a5ff6058e586.json'
           }); 

     // Instantiates a client
     //const speech = Speech();

     // The encoding of the audio file, e.g. 'LINEAR16'
      const encoding = 'LINEAR16';

     // The sample rate of the audio file in hertz, e.g. 16000
     const sampleRateHertz = 16000;

     // The BCP-47 language code to use, e.g. 'en-US'
      const languageCode = 'en-US';

     const request = {
       config: {
         encoding: encoding,
         sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
         languageCode: languageCode
       },
       interimResults: true, // If you want interim results, set this to true
       singleUtterance: false
     };

     // Create a recognize stream
     const recognizeStream = speech.streamingRecognize(request)
       .on('error', console.error)
       .on('data', (data) =>
           process.stdout.write(
             (data.results[0] && data.results[0].alternatives[0])
               ? `Transcription: ${data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript}\n`
               : `\n\nReached transcription time limit, press Ctrl+C\n`));

     // Start recording and send the microphone input to the Speech API
    record
       .start({
         sampleRateHertz: sampleRateHertz,
         threshold: 20,
         // Other options, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-record-lpcm16#options
         verbose: false,
         recordProgram: 'sox', // Try also "arecord" or "sox"
         silence: '10.0',
         device : 'plughw:0'
       //  device : settingsRecord.audio_input
       })
       .on('error', console.error)
       .pipe(recognizeStream);

     console.log('Listening, press Ctrl+C to stop.');
     // [END speech_streaming_mic_recognize]

    /* .command(
       `listen`,
       `Detects speech in a microphone input stream. This command requires that you have SoX installed and available in your $PATH. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-record-lpcm16#dependencies`,
       {},
       (opts) => streamingMicRecognize(opts.encoding, opts.sampleRateHertz, opts.languageCode)
     )
     .options({
       encoding: {
         alias: 'e',
         default: 'LINEAR16',
         global: true,
         requiresArg: true,
         type: 'string'
       },
       sampleRateHertz: {
         alias: 'r',
         default: 16000,
         global: true,
         requiresArg: true,
         type: 'number'
       },
       languageCode: {
         alias: 'l',
         default: 'en-US',
         global: true,
         requiresArg: true,
         type: 'string'
       }
     }) */
   }
   streamingMicRecognize();
   ```

Comment: Please elaborate your question with some code you are using like how you are giving the local file and how you going to access the live stream. without it is hard to help.

Comment: hi charan,i have included the code please tru to help me